# Android notifications - push notifications for multiple users

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I am writing an app in which you can create and invite multiple users to an event. I would like to have the app send notifications to users when they are invited to an event. I am calling the following in my button onClick method to send notifications when an event is created.

```
private void addNotification() {
    NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify=new Notification.Builder
            (getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Hello").setContentText("This is a notification").
            setContentTitle("notif").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build();

    notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.notify(0, notify);
}
```

This works, however this only sends the push notification to me when the event is created. I'm not sure how to have it send to the multiple people invited to the event. I have a list of the user emails I want to notify. How can i change this code to send a notification to multiple users?

Comment: You need to have a server and the server should send push using firebase messaging.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use google cloud messaging. It will help you to broadcast the notification to multiple users

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: ok thanks, so is this the only way to do it? no way to do it directly through Android's notification manager?